# Cannot read ios message from firebase push notification in ionic app

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification

I'm Just setting up push notifications for my app. They've been working welll on android for months and they display a toast when they come in while the app is open. I've been trying to enable them on ios and they're coming through in the background perfectly but when the app is open I can't read the content of the message. What I'm receiving is this:

`{"google.c.a.c_l":"notification","google.c.a.e":"1","aps":{"alert":"local"},"gcm.n.e":"1","google.c.a.c_id":"63900123618947024","google.c.a.udt":"0","gcm.message_id":"0:1535060571041708%93cc4aea93cc4aea","google.c.a.ts":"1535060570","tap":false}`

My guess is that the content is somehow stored in the `gcm.message_id` but I don't know how to access this. It seems like something that should be straight forward but I can't for the life of me figure it out!

Comment: Did you generate the APNS certificates as [described in this article](https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59)?

Comment: @JamesPoag I generated the certificates and the notifications are sending to the device when the app is in the background, so I dont think its the apple config, but again I'm not sure really

Comment: Ok, sorry.  I misunderstood your problem.